# Delete Image attachement after publishing product

Tags: php, woocommerce

I'm using Amazon S3 for storing my product images. That means there is no need to keep them on my WordPress server when the product is published.
In the Media Cloud plugin, which I'm using to auto upload the images (and for imgix), is a setting to delete the images immediately after upload.

I had to switch that off because of some mapping jobs has to be done on the image and the product metadata. When the mapping and the publishing are done however the image file may be deleted.

I've tried it using this code:

```
$post_id = get_the_ID();
$post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id );
wp_delete_file($post_thumbnail_id);
```

but it is not working. Got a 500 white screen. What to do...?

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by using this code:

```
// Delete the file from WordPress server after processing.
      $filename_only = wp_basename( get_attached_file( $post_thumbnail_id ) );
      $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
      $dir = $upload_dir['basedir'] .'/'. date('Y') . '/' . date ('m');
      $file = $dir . '/' . $filename_only;


      if ( ! empty ($file)){
       chdir($dir);
       unlink($filename_only);

      }
```

I fetched the filename and the upload directory first. Then I checked if the file exists in the directory and if so the working directory is changed to the local upload directory and delete the file.