# How to retrieve the date of a post

Tags: php, wordpress

I need the year and the month from the date a post is published.

In my case, the displayed post is from December 15th, 2018.

I'm using

```
<?php $date = get_the_date(Y,m);
  $delete_file = wp_upload_dir($date);?>
<pre>
  <?php print_r ($delete_file);?>
</pre>
```

But only gets the current Year and month:

```
Array
(
[path] => http://my-domain/wp-content/uploads/2019/01
[url] => http://my-domain/wp-content/uploads/2019/01
[subdir] => /2019/01
[basedir] => http://my-domain/wp-content/uploads
[baseurl] => http://my-domain/wp-content/uploads
[error] => 
)
```

I was hoping to see on [subdir] => 2018/12.
I hope I did understand the codex correctly as it tells me that it defaults to the current post.

And if I view another post, let's say from January 2017, I hope to see 2017/01

My goal is to build a url which I can use to delete an uploaded file after a post is published. If you are interested you can see my question about it here: [Delete Image attachement after publishing product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54219480/delete-image-attachement-after-publishing-product)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible reason why it doesn't work could be that you don't use it inside the loop or not on a page that displays a single post.

If that's the case you can still add the post id to make it work, like `get_the_date( 'Y,m', $post_id );`

Comment: I tried that but I get still 2019/01 returned. I also cat a bunch of notices that Y and m are undefined constants. Could that have something to do with it? BTW I am viewing woocommerce single product pages.

Comment: I suppose the 'Y,m'  has to be in single quotes, like in my answer.

Comment: I reviewed and it was ok. I cleared the caches and there it was. Great, thanks. I will mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: Glad it works. BTW, this page https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_upload_dir/ says that the time/date in `wp_upload_dir()` has to be formatted like 'yyyy/mm', so in your case that would be `'Y/m'` instead of `'Y,m'`. But if it works as it is, forget that....

Answer (score 0):

`get_the_date( string $d = '', int|WP_Post $post = null )` Gets the date of the post

`$d`
(string) (Optional) PHP date format defaults to the date_format option if not specified.

Here is an example of a date format you are looking for:
`Y/m` - returns 2019/01 for example

And this is how your function call should look like `get_the_date('Y/m')`,
Pay attention, Y/m is under quotation marks. It's a string.

Here https://codex.wordpress.org/Formatting_Date_and_Time you can find WordPress Date and Time Formatting examples...

`int|WP_Post $post = null` another optional parameter that function accepts is Post id, you can get it with `get_the_ID();`

Comment: Tried this already 'Y/m' returns [subdir] => /6PM6/ in the array.

Comment: Try to add postID as a second parameter. What happens then?

Comment: And also there is another function for getting post date: `the_date('Y/m')`. What do you get as a result?

Comment: Still 2019/01 as [subdir] in the array... with or without post ID.

Comment: Was that your goal? To get 2019/01? Or what?